# Discord.py: How to add another multi-word parameter in a command function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a announcement function which would send the necessary embed into the channel I specified. I have added the text that has to be sent but now I want it to include images as well.

> I can't send links of images inside the embed as they won't work.

I want to send another parameter that will include the image link and send it separately into the chat. I have tried it but it was only for one single image. But when we wanted to enter one more it wouldn't work. I am trying to understand on how to do it.

The following is my code for the command I am working on.

```
@nd.command()
async def announce(ctx, channel, *, message):
    townannouncerole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=834684222441521193)

    townannouncementchannel = nd.get_channel(834675349409234974)

    if str(channel.lower()) == 'town':
        if townannouncerole in ctx.author.roles:
            townannouncementembed = discord.Embed(title="Town Announcement", description=message, color=discord.Colour.random())
            townannouncementembed.set_author(name=ctx.author)
            townannouncementembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
            await townannouncementchannel.send(embed=townannouncementembed)
        
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you lack necessary permissions for this command!")
```

This is the code I used to send a single image and it worked fine.

```
@nd.command()
async def announce(ctx, channel, images, *, message):
    townannouncerole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=834684222441521193)

    townannouncementchannel = nd.get_channel(834675349409234974)

    if str(channel.lower()) == 'town':
        if townannouncerole in ctx.author.roles:
            townannouncementembed = discord.Embed(title="Town Announcement", description=message, color=discord.Colour.random())
            townannouncementembed.set_author(name=ctx.author)
            townannouncementembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
            await townannouncementchannel.send(embed=townannouncementembed)
            await townannouncementchannel.send(images)
        
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you lack necessary permissions for this command!")
```

Now the issue is I am not able to understand on **How can I send multiple links into the chat by adding another multi-word parameter like the `message` one that will include every text after it.** It is not necessary that you keep the parameters in the order. You can shuffle it in any way you want, to explain and solve.

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add another multiword parameter into a discord bot command, but what you can do is wait for another response, let me explain:

You can do like this:

```
@nd.command(name = "sending_links", aliases = ["send_link", "links_send"])
async def sending_links(ctx, channel):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    ctx.send("what links do you want to send? if you want to send many just seperate with \", 
    \" ex. www.image1.com, www.image2.com")
    response = await nd.wait_for("message", timeout=60)
    response = response.content.split(", ")
    for link in response:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "title", description = "description")
        embed.set_image(url = link)
        channel.send(embed = embed)
```

> I can't send links of images inside the embed as they won't work.

Yes you can send an image into an embed if you do `embed.set_image(url = image_url)`

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Comment: I meant not in the body of the EMBED. I can use `set_image` but it will only work for one.

Answer (score 0):

discord.py does not allow to use keyword arguments. So you need to make a argument parser.

Example: !announce --message 'your message' --image 'url'

So you can to it with splitting content from "--" and user arguments as you want.